# Pipe stderr and stdout separately in bash/sh

Tags: linux, bash, shell, dd

I've been trying to use the following command on my server
`dd if=/dev/zero bs=1M count=1024 | md5sum`

The output:

```
1024+0 records in
1024+0 records out
1073741824 bytes (1.1 GB) copied, 2.92245 s, 367 MB/s
cd573cfaace07e7949bc0c46028904ff  -
```

How do I let it show the speed (`367 MB/s`) as output only? The status is printed to `stderr`.

I'm currently using `awk` but it showed the md5 hash.

Helps are appreciated :)

Comment: Do you *need* the `md5sum`? Or is `of=/dev/null` also adequate?

Comment: @Carpetsmoker Yes I need md5sum.

Comment: Do you need _only_ the speed, or the hash too?

Comment: Just speed (like 367 MB/s)

Comment: I'm not sure what is the purpose of this command. You surely won't test MD5 calculation speed, but rather speed of reading from /dev/zero (or any other source). Are you sure `| md5sum` is at all relevant?

Comment: Same question as @mike.dld

Comment: Or, is there a way to show the second last output? I'm pretty sure that there is a way.

Comment: The problem isn't so much in showing the output, the problem is piping the stdout to `md5sum`, while piping the `stderr` to something else (ie. `awk`, or whatever). This is surprisingly complicated to do.

Comment: @Carpetsmoker +1. Quite easy with temporary file, but yeah, complicated without it.

Comment: @mike.dld Temporary file is ok.

Answer (score 4):

First, a function to simulate your command

```
simulation() { 
  echo "1024+0 records in
1024+0 records out
1073741824 bytes (1.1 GB) copied, 2.92245 s, 367 MB/s" >&2
  echo "cd573cfaace07e7949bc0c46028904ff  -"
}

$ simulation >/dev/null
1024+0 records in
1024+0 records out
1073741824 bytes (1.1 GB) copied, 2.92245 s, 367 MB/s

$ simulation 2>/dev/null
cd573cfaace07e7949bc0c46028904ff  -
```

Then, the solution: redirecting stderr to a process substitution that displays the desired output back to stderr, capturing stdout in a variable.

```
$ md5sum=$( simulation 2> >(sed -n '/MB\/s/ {s/.*, //p; q}' >&2) )
367 MB/s

$ echo $md5sum
cd573cfaace07e7949bc0c46028904ff -
```

Comment: To clarify, you need to replace `simulation` with just the `dd` command, and put the `| md5sum` right *before* the last closing parenthesis, ie: `>&2) | md5sum )`